# NetworkXのネットワーク分析エラー

Tags: python, networkx

NetworkXのKernighan-linアルゴリズムを用いて手持ちのネットワーク
データの分割を行ったのですが、以下のエラーで躓いてしまいました。
アドバイス頂けますと幸いです。

```
IndexError Traceback (most recent call last) in () 17 for c in init_partition: 18 for n in c: ---> 19 color_map_i[n]=colors[counter] 20 counter=counter+1 21

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

コードは以下の通りです。

```
G=nx.read_edgelist("200224_04_act.prn",nodetype=int)

colors=["red","blue","green"]
pos=nx.spring_layout(G)


init_nodes=np.array_split(G.nodes(),2)
init_partition=[set(init_nodes[0]),set(init_nodes[1])]
print(init_partition)


from networkx.algorithms.community import kernighan_lin_bisection

color_map_i=["black"]*nx.number_of_nodes(G)
print(color_map_i)
counter=0
for c in init_partition:
    for n in c:
        color_map_i[n]=colors[counter]
    counter=counter+1

print(color_map_i)


nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_color=color_map_i)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos)

plt.axis("off")
plt.show()

lst_b=kernighan_lin_bisection(G,partition=init_partition)
color_map_b=["black"]*nx.number_of_nodes(G)

counter=0
for c in lst_b:
    for n in c:
        color_map_b[n]=colors[counter]
    counter=counter+1

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_color=color_map_b)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

元データ "200224_04_act.prn" は以下の通りですが、当投稿の文字数制限により実際より数が小さいです。（ノード数は実際には2000程度）

```
   1     415
   2     415
   3     415
   3    1350
   4    1351
   5    1352
   6     383
   7     993
   8    1353
   9     887
  10     887
  11     887
  12     887
  13     887
  14    1185
  15    1185
  16    1185
  17    1185
  18    1185
  19    1146
  20    1146
  21    1146
  22    1146
  21     776
  23     776
  24     707
  25     707
  26     707
  27     707
  28     707
  29     754
  21     754
  30     754
  31     754
  32     754
  33     778
  34     778
  35     778
  36     778
  37     778
  38     859
  39     859
  40    1354
  41     563
  42     563
  43     563
  44     563
  45     563
  46    1209
  47    1209
  48    1209
  49    1209
  50    1209
  51     715
  52     715
  53     715
  54     715
  55     715
  56    1048
  57    1048
  58    1047
  59    1047
  60    1047
```

Answer (score 0):

この部分に問題があります。

```
counter=0
for c in init_partition:
    for n in c:
        color_map_i[n]=colors[counter]
    counter=counter+1
```

`n` には頂点の名前が入っていますが、 200224_04_act.prn を見る限りこれは 1 から始まっているようです。しかし Python の配列の添え字は 0 から始まっているため、`color_map_i[n]` と書くとひとつずれます。このため最大の番号の頂点の名前が `n` に入っている場合、`color_map_i[n]` は存在せず `index out of range` エラーに繋がります。

解決法として：

- 200224_04_act.prn の頂点番号を 0 から始める、または、
- `color_map_i[n-1]` のようにすべての箇所でひとつずらす、または、
- `color_map_i` の長さを `nx.number_of_nodes(G) + 1` にし、添え字番号と頂点番号が対応するようにする

が考えられます。

<sub>補足：ところで `counter` はわざわざ自分でインクリメントする必要はなくて、`for counter, c in enumerate(init_partition):` と書くと勝手に添え字を代入してくれます。</sub>

Comment: nekketsuuさん　ご助言頂き有難うございます。解決法もパターンに分けて頂き大変助かりました。初歩的な部分での躓きだったのですね。counterの部分も含めて勉強してみます。取り急ぎ、詰まっていた場所はerrorを克服できました！

Comment: 良かったです :)　他にエラーがあれば別個に質問を立てていただければと思います。回答の横にあるチェックマークを押すことで回答を承認することもできますので、もし良ければお試しください。